# Show that $f(x)\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I was in my analysis exam and this exercise was required but I could´t do it. 
Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function in all the domain. Show that, if $$\inf\{f'(x):x>0\}>0$$then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. 
My attemps was around that $f$ is increasing, and to use sequences such that go to $\infty$ but it was not useful.

Comment: Could you be kind enough to show your efforts at solving the problem? This will help me and others avoid including "redundant" details in our answers, e.g. repeating a part of the solution process you've already made progress on and/or clearly understand.

Comment: @AlannRosas My attemps was around that $f$ is increasing, by contradiction, I supposed that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L<\infty$ and I took a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to\infty$ with the idea to find a contradiction with $f(x_n)\to L$, but I could't.

Comment: HINT: Try using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: @AntonioHernandez thank you for this info!

Comment: If $f'(x) \geq C$ for all $x$ and for some $C \gt 0$ then $f(x) \geq Cx + f(0)$ for all $x.$

Comment: @AlannRosas thanks to you!

Comment: @AntonioHernandez don't thank me. Thank Rabin for their answer :)

Comment: I see two answers that make use of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but it seems to me that in order to apply that theorem one would require the additional hypothesis that $f'$ is Riemann-integrable on any interval $[0,x]$ for $x>0$. There are functions which are differentiable everywhere but their derivatives are not Riemann-integrable.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to note that if
$$\inf \;\{f'(x):x>0\}>0$$
then
$$\inf \;\{f'(x):x>0\}=\delta$$
for some $\delta>0$.

So,
$$f^\prime(x)\geq \delta$$
for all $x>0$, because if not, then it would contradict $\inf \;\{f'(x):x>0\}=\delta$.

Now,
$$f(x)=\int_{0}^M f^\prime (x)\geq \int_{0}^M\delta$$
which tends to infinity as $x\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

By the assumption, we know that

$$\inf\{f'(x),x>0\}=M>0$$

Thus, there exists $X\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\geq X$ implies

$$f'(x)>\frac{M}{2}$$

But then for $x\geq X$ we have

$$f(x)=\int_X^x f'(x)dx+f(X)\geq \int_X^x \frac{M}{2}dx+f(X)=\frac{M}{2}(x-X)+f(X)$$

Thus, $f(x)$ grows at least linearly for $x\geq X$.